# How to read complete line in 'for' loop with spaces

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am trying to run a `for` loop for file and I want to display whole line.
But instead its displaying last word only. I want the complete line.

```
for j in `cat ./file_wget_med`

do
echo $j

done
```

result after run:

```
Found.
```

Here is my data:

```
$ cat file_wget_med
2013-09-11 14:27:03 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084257/bash-array-with-spaces-in-elements

Answer (score 301):

`for` loop splits when it sees any whitespace like space, tab, or newline. So, you should use [IFS (Internal Field Separator)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16192/what-is-ifs-in-context-of-for-looping):

```bsh
IFS=$'\n'       # make newlines the only separator
for j in $(cat ./file_wget_med)    
do
    echo "$j"
done
# Note: IFS needs to be reset to default!
```

Comment: And put care about single quotes on IFS because IFS=$"\n" will split also "nn" strings. I found set IFS more reliable than use more complicated syntax or functions.

Comment: apparently it is advised to `unset IFS` afterwards, so that other commands are not influenced in this same shell.

Comment: What does the `$` mean in `IFS=$'\n'`?

Comment: `$` makes line breaks work inside the string. This should also be done with `local IFS=$'\n'` inside a function.

Comment: @Renn that's `$'...'` known "[ANSI-C Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html)"

Comment: This is great but **take note** that IFS will affect parameter substitution, too!  Thus `for x in ...; do $CMD $x; done` will _break_ if CMD is a command plus arguments.  For example, if `CMD='ls -l'` then the shell will look for a binary named "ls -l" instead of a binary named "ls" and including "-l" as a parameter.

Comment: If you `unset IFS` as suggested by @BorisDäppen, this will not really return the default behavior. Explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39545837/unset-ifs-unexpected-behaviour

Comment: [Bash Pitfall #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)

Comment: Something weird happens when there is an "n" in the string, so I would advise to use IFS=$'[real line break here that this comment won't show adequately]' instead.

Answer (score 127):

`for` loops split on any whitespace (space, tab, newline) by default; the easiest way to work on one *line* at a time is to use a `while read` loop instead, which splits on newlines:

```
while read i; do echo "$i"; done < ./file_wget_med
```

I would *expect* your command to spit out one word per line (that's what happened when I tested it out with a file of my own). If something else is happening, I'm not sure what could be causing it.

Comment: This is also a good alternative to `for i in \`ls\`; do echo $1; done`, by piping the output to the while command: `ls|while read i; do echo $i; done`. This works on file/folder names with spaces, without needing to change environment variables. Very good answer.

Comment: the while didn't handle the first and last lines very, not as well as the for loop with IFS

Comment: @jishi Since it's primarily designed for display, and is responsive to terminal-window size and such, `ls` is not considered safe for use with `|` (the pipe operator). `find` is more flexible in addition to being safer for this purpose.

Comment: @GrantBowman Depending on how the file is delimited, it might work better if you try `while read -r i` instead of just `while read i`.

Comment: This is a GREAT answer, I used it to turn a list I had into PLIST entries for an IOS app I was developing on mac OSX. I replaced the file input by piping the clipboad using **pbpaste** -> `pbpaste | while read t; do echo "<string>$t</string>"; done`

Comment: `ls -1` may be used with `|` to guarantee one-per-line unformatted output

Comment: @jishi the piping is actually a bit of an issue. It creates a sub shell where as the "< file" method doesn't. The new sub-shell has the side effect that changes inside the loop are not visible to outside world.

Comment: This is awesome because it works with the output of `tail -f`.  The `for` loop approach did not work for me, probably because it was waiting for all output to be produced before starting to process it.  (But the output of `tail -f` never ends.)

Comment: One can use `<<< "$string"` in bash when dealing with strings and not files.

Answer (score 23):

```
#!/bin/bash
files=`find <subdir> -name '*'`
while read -r fname; do
    echo $fname
done <<< "$files"
```

Verified working, not the one liner you probably want but it's not possible to do so elegantly.

Comment: a here-string! most elegant of all other solutions IMO

Comment: Notice that it works with bash but not with other shells like dash for example.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a slight extension to Mitchell Currie's answer, that I like because of the small scope of side effects, which avoids having to set a variable:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r fname; do
    echo $fname
done <<< "`find <subdir>`"
```

Comment: You could remove `-name '*'` and it would be the same, no?

Answer (score 6):

I would write it like this:

```
cat ./file_wget_med | while read -r j
do
    echo $j
done
```

as it requires least changes in the original script (except for the solution using `IFS`, but it modifies `bash` behavior not only for this loop control statement).

Comment: Pipe and `cat` are unnecessary here. `while` loop accepts redirection just fine, which is why this is usually written as `while IFS= read -r line; do...done < input.txt`

Answer (score 3):

[Mapfile](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/mapfile) is a convenient way to read lines from a file into an indexed array, not as portable as [read](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/read) but slightly faster. By using for loop you avoid creating a subshell.

```
#!/bin/bash

mapfile -t < file.txt

for line in "${MAPFILE[@]}"; do
    echo $line
done
```

Keep in mind when using pipelines, it will put the while loop in a subshell. Changes inside the while loop like variables will not propagate to outer part of the script.

**Example:**

```
#!/bin/bash

a=0
printf %s\\n {0..5} | while read; do
  ((a++))
done
echo $a # 'a' will always be 0.
```

**(Better solution):**

```
#!/bin/bash

b=0
while read; do
  ((b++))
done < <(printf %s\\n {0..5})

echo $b # 'b' equal to 6 (works as expected).
```

Comment: OMG yes!  I was launching tasks in the background, and using jobs/wait to control how many at a time.  Until I found your "better solution" jobs/wait didn't see the background processes.

Answer (score -1):

Dandalf got real close to a functional solution, but one should NOT EVER be trying to assign the result of unknown amounts of input (i.e. `find ~/.gdfuse -name '*'`) to variables! Or, at least be trying to do such a thing via an array variable; if you insist on being so lazy! So, here's Dandalf's solution done without the dangerous maneuver; and in all in one line

```
while read -r fname; do
  echo $fname;
done <<< `find ~/.gdfuse -name '*'
```

Comment: Hey @odoncaoa , I tried to do the find command without the double quotes, but it makes all of the results appear as one line. I am confused about the "unknown amounts of input" with this command and the dangers involved. Can you provide an example of the dangers and how they could theoretically happen? I seriously do not desire to be lazy about it, I am just more comfortable in other programming languages.

Comment: @Dandalf they are likely referring to memory leaks; storing potentially gigabytes of data in a variable is not a good idea unless you have a lot of RAM