# for f in files returns sections separated by space

Tags: command-line, bash, files

I have the following code

```
arrFiles[0]=0
cd "/home/thenok/Documents/Link to thought diary"
for i in $(find -type f ! -name "*~"); do
arrFiles[0]=$[arrFiles[0]+1]
arrFiles[arrFiles[0]]="$i" 
echo "    pos ${arrFiles[0]} file ${arrFiles[arrFiles[0]]}"
done
```

but it outputs to (13 and 23 are files)

```
pos 354 file ./Link
pos 355 file to
pos 356 file diary/201504/quint/13
pos 357 file ./Link
pos 358 file to
pos 359 file diary/201511/23
```

which is bad because when using another command (stat) instead of echo it gives me

```
stat: cannot stat ‘./Link’: No such file or directory
stat: cannot stat ‘to’: No such file or directory
stat: cannot stat ‘thought’: No such file or directory
stat: cannot stat ‘diary/201411/done/31’: No such file or directory
```

I tried:
1: using a direct path instead of a link, 2:

```
arrFiles[0]=0
FILES="/home/thenok/Documents/Link to thought diary/*"
for i in "$FILES"; do
arrFiles[0]=$[arrFiles[0]+1]
arrFiles[arrFiles[0]]="$i" 
echo "    pos ${arrFiles[0]} file ${arrFiles[arrFiles[0]]}"
done
#result is pos 1 file /home/thenok/Documents/Link to thought diary/*
```

3: making the array directly doesn't use subfolders

```
arrFiles=( "/home/thenok/Documents/Link to thought diary/"* )
for f in "${arrFiles[@]}"
do
stat -c %s "$f"
echo "$f"
done
```

Solution found at [How to read complete line in 'for' loop with spaces](https://askubuntu.com/questions/344407/how-to-read-complete-line-in-for-loop-with-spaces) which is exactly what i wanted in the first place but didnt know how to write in google

```
IFS=$'\n'       # make newlines the only separator
arrFiles[0]=0
cd "/home/thenok/Documents/Link to thought diary"
for i in $(find "/home/thenok/Documents/Link to thought diary/" -type f ! -name "*~"); do
arrFiles[0]=$[arrFiles[0]+1]
arrFiles[arrFiles[0]]="$i" 
echo "    pos ${arrFiles[0]} file ${arrFiles[arrFiles[0]]}"
done
```

output is

```
pos 10 file /home/thenok/Documents/Link to thought diary/Link to diary/201408/methinks questions.txt
pos 11 file /home/thenok/Documents/Link to thought diary/Link to diary/201408/methinks small.txt
pos 12 file /home/thenok/Documents/Link to thought diary/Link to diary/201408/methinks2.txt
pos 13 file /home/thenok/Documents/Link to thought diary/Link to diary/201408/methinkss.txt
pos 14 file /home/thenok/Documents/Link to thought diary/Link to diary/201408/myfile.txt
pos 15 file /home/thenok/Documents/Link to thought diary/Link to diary/201408/new  2.txt
```

Comment: Quote the vars, also prefer find over bash

Comment: -1 for repeatedly changing the question. This is looking like [an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/270345).

Answer (score 3):

[Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/70524)

Do it thus:

```
FILES="/home/thenok/Documents/Link to thought diary/"
for f in "$FILES"/*
do
    stat "$f"
done
```

If you use `find`, use its `-exec` command:

```
find "/home/thenok/Documents/Link to thought diary/" -type f ! -name '*~' -exec stat {} +
```

[Never do `for f in $(find ...)`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

If you want an array, just create one directly:

```
arrFiles=( "/home/thenok/Documents/Link to thought diary/"* )
```

Then do:

```
for f in "${arrFiles[@]}"
do
    stat -c %s "$f"
done
```

Instead of looping over indices. Even then, you don't need to save the length of an array manually. You can get it through `${#arrFiles[@]}`.

Comment: doesnt work so far, i need to put in an array, wait a sec to update question (your code works for echo and stat, but not array)

Comment: @ThenEnok how are you putting it in an array?

Comment: @ThenEnok see update.

Comment: how can i edit for f in "${arrFiles[@]}" so that it give files in subfolders? :)

Comment: @ThenEnok You don't. You edit `arrfiles=( ".../"* )` to use recursive globs: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/49917/70524